# Number of ways generating $N$ length strings?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need to learn approach to solve following problem, I need this for programming problem.

For a given set of alphabet letters $S$, and pairs of rule and find the number of ways in which $N$ length different strings can be formed.

$\underline{Examples}:$

Given a set of letters $S=\{a, b, c\}$, we have replacement rules $(current\_letter, next\_ letter)$ as below:

$$
\{
 (a, a),
 (a, b), 
 (a, c),
 (b, a),
 (b, c),
 (c, a),
 (c, b)
\}
$$

How to calculate the number of ways that $N$ length string can be formed such that two consecutive pairs always appears in replacement rules.

For $N = 1$, we have 3 ways either { "$a$", "$b$", "$c$" }
For $N=2$, we have 7 ways { "$aa$"
"$ab$",
"$ac$",
"$ba$",
"$bc$",
"$ca$",
"$cb$"  }
For $N=3$, we have 17 ways { "$aaa$",
"$aab$",
"$aac$",
"$aba$",
"$abc$",
"$aca$",
"$acb$",
"$baa$",
"$bab$",
"$bac$",
"$bca$",
"$bcb$",
"$caa$",
"$cab$",
"$cac$",
"$cba$",
"$cbc$" }

Please give me hint, what should I read to sovle this?

Comment: The rules prohibit having consecutive $b$s or consecutive $c$s.  Have you tried to construct a recurrence relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but especially because you need it for programming I think it might be useful.

For $n=1,2,\dots$ let $A_n,B_n,C_n$ denote the number of stringths having length $n$ that end on $a,b,c$ respectively, and let $T_n$ denote the number of stringth having length $n$.

Then $A_1=B_1=C_1=1$ and:

- $T_n=A_n+B_n+C_n$
- $A_{n+1}=T_n$
- $B_{n+1}=A_n+C_n$
- $C_{n+1}=A_n+B_n$

Comment: Thanks, I will explore on it further

Comment: You welcome. Good luck.

Comment: helped me very much.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to counting the number of paths of length $N-1$ in a directed graph whose vertices are letters, and where there is an edge from $v$ to $w$ if and only if $(v,w)$ is a rule. Letting $A$ be the adjacency matrix of this graph, where $A_{i,j}=1$ if there is an edge from $i$ to $j$ and $A_{i,j}=0$ if not, it is well known that the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^k$ gives the number of directed paths of length exactly $k$ from $i$ to $j$. Therefore, to compute the number of all paths, you just need to add up all the entries in the matrix exponent $A^{N-1}$. This can be computed in $|S|^3\log N$ time using exponentiation by squaring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I draw the execution tree by hand (like I drawn in linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621550/a-puzzle-related-to-nested-loops/13622284)) It was tree for me instead ... indeed I am looking for an efficient solution --- my current implement ion not good when $N  > 1000000$